# How do I increase the number of variations in a Django product model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a product variation as below. It works but only allows me to add an additional 10 variations. I need to add 25 variations of the product. How can I change it so that it allows me to add more than 10 variations in the model?

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) #refer none == unlimited amount

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... where is the restriction?

Comment: When I go into django admin, I need to add 25 different variations, when i get to 10 variations, it does not let me add any more variations.

Comment: Can you show `admin.py` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @neverwalkaloner I checked my admin.py and it had `max_num = 10` so I have now changed it to 25 as so:

```
class VariationInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Variation
    extra = 0
    max_num = 25
```

It now has a limit of 25.